# php - for loop inside a while loop, correct syntax?

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I have this loop

```
while (count($arr) < 7)
        {

            $string = 'xx';
            for ($i=0; strlen($string) < 4; $i++)
            {
                $string = $string.'1';
            }
            echo "<br>array length is less than 7, word $string is created.";
            $arr[] = $string;
        }
```

Every time I run this part of the code, my xampp local server would time out and gives the server not found error.

I have found that if I delete the inner `for` loop, it would run fine. Is there anything wrong with putting the `for` loop inside the `while` loop?

Also, my conditional statement `strlen($string) < 4` in the `for` loop does not have any reference to the `$i` variable, but I don't see any thing not logical of having a conditional statement not related to the counter.  Am I wrong, does it require some sort of comparison against the counter?

TIA

Comment: You never use `$i`, so you can change it to `while( strlen($string) < 4)`

Comment: Server not found error?? What's that got to do with php syntax?

Comment: I see absolutely nothing wrong with it.. I'll keep looking thought..

Comment: at first glance it looks fine & nothing to do with nested loops. Personally I use NetBeans; you might choose Eclipse, Zend, etc. But, if you don't have a debugger to step through your code you are not going to get far.

Comment: Nick, she may want to use it later. Nothing wrong with it, unless you suspect it's causing the error somehow.. The only way it could be causing an error is if $string was assigned before to it by reference, which I doubt. $string=&$i would cause errors like this...

Comment: The exact code works perfectly for me. Don't see anything wrong with it, either.

Comment: Thanks all, I don't see anything wrong with the code either, but the for loop is somehow cause the server to hang.  Also, I do use the $i variable for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with having a for inside a while.

Your "for" would be better a bit clearer as

```
while(strlen($string) < 4) {
    $string = $string.'1';
}
```

Comment: Thanks John, the reason I have $i is because I am using $i as an array index, that part of the code was left out.

Comment: Well, your PHP is valid and works for me - problem must be elsewhere (perhaps in some of the code you've omitted?)

Comment: Thanks again, I am walking through my very short omitted code to see if there is any thing else.  At least I know the error is not due to the loops.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues whatsoever with your php.

I copied your code exactly and there was no infinite loop at all.

The result I got was as follows:

```
<br>array length is less than 7, word xx11 is created.
<br>array length is less than 7, word xx11 is created.
<br>array length is less than 7, word xx11 is created.
<br>array length is less than 7, word xx11 is created.
<br>array length is less than 7, word xx11 is created.
<br>array length is less than 7, word xx11 is created.
<br>array length is less than 7, word xx11 is created.
```

My only suggestion would be to change:

```
$string = $string.'1';
```

to

```
$string .= '1';
```

Comment: Thanks Brian for testing the code, I edited the code for use as an example, not a real code.